# Display specific nodes on specific pages

Tags: views, nodes

How do I display specific nodes from a view on specific pages?

For example, I create a CCK field ("Display on node id:") for the content type *Ads*, and put there IDs of content type *Basic page* where I want display this *Ads*.

Is there to achieve this without additional modules?

Answer (score 0):

Create a block display mode for that view (the view that display ads) and place that block on basic page node types.

In the view you should add a Contextual filter (under Advanced settings) and validate it as the node ID from URL. Then add a filter that selects only ads for that node ID.

Comment: Thanks, but don't work if enter multiply values in CCK fields ("Display on node id:"), example "10,19". Maybe need use "PHP code" validation?

Comment: you enter multiple values delimited by "," ? There is an option in the field settings that allows you to add multiple values (you should select "Unlimited"). When you edit the node you'll have a button saying "Add more" or something like that, which loads another field to enter the new value